# Laravel blade is not working correctly on server side

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've a Laravel 8 project. Everything is working well on my windows local but when I deploy it to server, it fails due to Blade thing.
By the way, I'm pulling my project from github and later uploading the vendor folder.Blade is not processed, printed as a text

[image]

Comment: what you mean with working well? you got an 500, 404 error or you missing only some styles?

Comment: It goes to 500, and I don't think it is about styling because it is working on local server.

Comment: you should check that 500 error message - it should give you an idea what is happening

Comment: Can we see the laravel.log file errors in your deployed environment?

Comment: Maybe your local environment is Windows and server is Linux,so part of code that is not a problem in Windows, but in Linux it causes problems, for example, uppercase and lowercase letters are same in Windows but are different meaning in Linux.Check this possibility

Comment: composer install // npm install ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using quotes before @include, try removing them

Comment: No, I'm not using anything. Everyting is well on local server. It is just printing textplain @include. I'dont know why there are quotes